# PHP Array Differences - Generated by Loop vs String Comma-Separated

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, arrays

I am using jQuery Autocomplete (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/) and having some problems when I use an array generated by a MySQL call. Is there a fundamental difference between an array created in PHP using strings versus creating one in a loop?

For example, if I create array using string, like in the example, everything works fine. ie:

```
$items = array(
    "Great Bittern" => "Botaurus stellaris",
    "Little Grebe" => "Tachybaptus ruficollis")
```

When I create the array as below, it seems the array is not recognized, or maybe the data within the array is not searchable:

```
$items = array();
$query = mysql_query("MY QUERY");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
array_push($data, $row['name']);
}
```

Is it because the MySQL call is made after the php file including it has been loaded? I've experimented with many, many variations of creating the array in the loop, and none have worked.

Thanks in advance for any advice or tips. Pulling my hair out over this one!

Comment: Apart from that the first one is an associative array and the second one a numerical one, you are not appending to `$items` in the second example. If you do it right, then there is no difference between a "normal" array and one populated in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples do fundamentally different things.

In the first example, you have what most languages would call a "hash" or a "map"; a series of key/value pairs mapping one string to another. "Great Bittern" would be the key, and "Botaurus stellaris" would be the corrosponding value.

In the second you have a more traditional numerically indexed array with sequential keys. There is nothing preventing you from creating a map the way you did in the first example, you simply need to explicitly specify the string key instead of using `array_push`. If your query is returning two associated values, you would do something like

```
$data[$row['key']] = $row['value'];
```

Which approach you use depends on what kind of data your jQuery plugin expects to receive. Does it want a key/value map, or an array of values?

Comment: @dwarbi As I said in my example, you simply assign a new value to a new key by using `$data[$new_key] = $new_value`. If you don't have specific keys, then just use `array_push`. The important question is, which form of array do you need to supply to your jQuery plugin?

Comment: Thanks for that - I did realize my followup comment was a silly one.

Comment: So, I did try this as well: in my loop, I added:
$items[$row['cityId']] = $row['name'];

When I print_r the array, the data is identical in format to the array given in the example. Shouldn't this be a hash/map array as well? This is what the jQuery plugin expects. This is why I think it might have to do with the order in which the pages/includes load.

Comment: @dwarbi How are you making the data available to the jQuery plugin? You'll have to output it in json or xml or some other encoding, again depending on what the plugin expects.

Comment: The example data that works is not encoded (as far as I can see) - just an array. But I see what your saying, it seems like it has to be. All I'm doing is replacing the array as it's created by the example, with my MySQL call.

Comment: The documentation indicates you can either pass an array via the `data` parameter, in which case you'll need to encode your PHP array as a JS array via `json_encode`, or you can tell the plugin to request the data via a GET request to a url which must serve your array as a `"\n"`-separated list of items.

Comment: meagar, I can't thank you enough! I was so focused on making it work on the server-side, I neglected to look at the client-side options. So while we don't have a definitive answer to this question, I can work around it. Thanks again!